# Export phone state

Tags: samsung

I've a galaxy s7 with many customisations: apps I've installed, folder structures, alarm apps , blue dimmer app etc.... is it possible to save the state of the s7 and transfer it to another Samsung phone (s8 for example) , so all apps and their state will also be transferred.